# Prometheus/Alertmanager inhibit rules

Tags: devops, prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

I have the following inhibit rule:

```
inhibit_rules:
- source_match:
    severity: 'critical'
  target_match:
    severity: 'high'
  equal: ['alertname]
```

and also two alerts accordingly with severity high and critical.

Alert 1

```
  - alert: ContainerCpuUsage
    expr: ContainerCpuUsage > 90
    for: 30m
    labels:
      severity: high
      topic: container
    annotations:
      summary: "Container CPU usage for pod '{{ $labels.pod }}' is above 90% for the last 30 minutes."
      description: "Container CPU usage (name {{ $labels.pod }})\nMeasuredValue={{ printf \"%.2f\" $value }}%"
```

Alert 2

```
  - alert: ContainerCpuUsage
    expr: ContainerCpuUsage > 98
    for: 30m
    labels:
      severity: critical
      topic: container
    annotations:
      summary: "Container CPU usage for pod '{{ $labels.pod }}' is above 98% for the last 30 minutes."
      description: "Container CPU usage (name {{ $labels.pod }})\nMeasuredValue={{ printf \"%.2f\" $value }}%"
```

The idea is when the CPU usage goes suddenly from 20%, let say, to 99% a critical alert should be fired and also a high alert should not be fired.With inhibit rules above it works perfectly.
But when the CPU usage goes suddenly from 20%, let say, to 91% a high alert is fired and this is correct.After some min if CPU usage goes further to 99% a second alert,a critical one is also fired.So i have in total 2 alerts open,high and critical.
What i want is that if CPU usage >98% high alert should be closed and only critical remains open.Why high alert is not closed/inhibit?

If an alert is already fired,can inhibit rules close it?

Answer (score 1):

The "inhibit_rules" just mutes the alerts, in other words, it prevents sending new notifications (emails, messages, etc) to recipients about the alerts, but does not inactive them.

Comment: in simple words it means if an alert is fired ,"inhibit_rules" will not close it?

Comment: No, a fired alert will stay "active" independently if it's inhibited or not.